# In CSS, for an internal Firefox table, how to select the first column?

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, userchrome.css

Firefox has its own special CSS selectors for working with tables within the web browser's UI (aka the ***original*** "Chrome").  Important note: I'm ***not*** referring to tables within websites.

I am trying to select the first row in the Bookmarks/History Library window.

In userChrome.css, I currently have:

```
@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/places/places.xhtml) {

  #placeContent::-moz-tree-column(1) {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
    color: lime !important;
  }

}
```

But this does not work.  I also tried:

```
@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/places/places.xhtml) {

  #placeContent::-moz-tree-column():first-of-type {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
    color: lime !important;
  }

}
```

and

```
@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/places/places.xhtml) {

  #placeContent::-moz-tree-column(1)::-moz-tree-cell-text() {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
    color: lime !important;
  }

}
```

and

```
@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/places/places.xhtml) {

  #placeContent td:first-child::-moz-tree-cell-text() {
    margin-left: -10px !important;
    color: lime !important;
  }

}
```

But these also do not work.

How can this be done?

Comment: FF won't know about this url `chrome://browser/...`

Comment: @MrT What makes you suggest that?  That's how Firefox works.  See the Firefox source code: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/search?q=chrome%3A%2F%2Fbrowser